# How to exclude from a user list those with less than X post?

Tags: wordpress

I have a user display list where alle the "contributors" are displayed, except those with no posts.

But what if I would like to exclude those with less than X (i.e. 4) posts?

Here's (part of) the code.

```html
/*
Template Name: Display Contributors and Authors
*/

    $args = array(
         'role'    => 'contributor',
         'orderby' => 'rand',
         'order'   => 'DESC'
    );

    // only return users with published posts
    $args['has_published_posts'] = true;
    // run the WP_Query
    $contributors = get_users( $args );

    ?>

<?php get_header();?>
<div id="main">
<div id="primary" class="four-parts archive">
<div class="widget-title">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
    <div id="blog-list" class="blog-category">
    <ul>    
        <?php

        foreach($contributors as $contributor) 

     {

        ?>
        <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can extend your code by checking each $contributor to see how many posts they have, and if they have less than 4 posts, we can use the continue keyword to exit out of the current loop iteration and go to the next one.  As shown here:

```
foreach($contributors as $contributor) {
  // this will return the number of posts by the contributor
  $count = count_user_posts($contributor->ID)
  if(count($posts) < 4) {
      continue;
  } 
  // your code goes here
  }
```

Comment: Mmm. I'm getting a syntax error.

I wrote down it this way:

`<?php

  foreach($contributors as $contributor) // this will return the number of posts by the contributor
  $count = count_user_posts($contributor->ID)
  if(count($posts) < 4) {
      continue;
  }
  
 
  {
  
  ?> 
//code here`

Comment: It looks like you are missing the opening bracket after the foreach statement.  Also the closing one.

Comment: I tried it again following your instructions but it doesn't work. The code is now this:
`<?php

  foreach($contributors as $contributor) {
  // this will return the number of posts by the contributor
  $count = count_user_posts($contributor->ID)
  if(count($posts) < 4) {
      continue;
  } ?>
//my code
} `

Comment: Can you tell me what is happening when you try that code?  Have you tried echoing the $count variable to see what it's returning for each user?

Comment: I get a syntax error on that lines. No I didn't. I will try it in a while. Thanks.